# Trying to center a ul list in a container inside... sprites in li a

Tags: html-lists, containers, center, sprite

Hello i am developing a web site.... its my second one, and i am trying to center a ul inside a div
i want to place icons in anchor tags and use background positioning for sprite use.... the thing is how can i set to center the ul inside the div or inside the ul ...
example of my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kowen/wAdf3/1/

here is the code: (html)

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
    <li><a class="fbicon" href="#">hola 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="twttricon" href="#">hola 2</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="sndcloudicon" href="#">hola 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a class="emailicon" href="#">hola 4</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
    #container {
    width: 400px;
    height:400px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:gray;
}
#container ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
#container li {
   /* float: left;*/
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-indent:-999em;
}
#container li a {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url(http://www.testcloud.com.ar/social-icons.png);
}
a.fbicon {
    background-position:-5px center;
}
a.twttricon {
    background-position:-42px center;
}
a.sndcloudicon {
    background-position:-111px center;
}
a.emailicon {
    background-position:-148px center;
}
```

i have tried a few recipes but no clue how can i do that....
how can i get the a displayed as a block so it can be shown the full icon on screen???
thanks in advance for your help.
Salutations